# Retrieve diff with 0 context lines using GitHub API in Python

Tags: python, github, github-api

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve a diff with 0 context files using the GitHub API. I've tried to use the following request:

```
requests.get('https://git.{org_name}.com/api/v3/repos/{OWNER}/{repo}/pulls/34623?context=0', headers=headers)
```

But unfortunately I still get the standard 3 lines of context. What I am trying to achieve is the same result as if I'm using the git diff -U0 command locally.

Is there any way I can accomplish by only using the requests module in Python?